# how to model complex if-then statements in integer programming

Tags: modeling, linear-programming

I am trying to model a if-then condition for a MIP. The MIP looks like

Maximize SUM_i H(i) - C

s.t.,

```
  SUM_j x(i, j) <= D(i) and 

  SUM_i x(i, j) <= S(j)
```

where H(i) = 1 if SUM_j x(i, j) = D(i), 0 otherwise

and C = SUM_i,j (if x(i, j) > 1 then 1, 0 otherwise)

I know how to model a simple if-then condition in an MIP. But not able to model this one.

Comment: This is difficult to read. I would suggest to make this a bit more pleasant to read (especially the math). Also is `x(i,j)` continuous or binary/integer?

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen. I have edited the question to make it a little more readable. Also, x(i, j) are Integer variables.

Comment: `SUM_i x(i, j) <= S(i)` looks wrong

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen. You are right. It should have been S(j). Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle this by introducing a slack variable `v` to the demand equation, and then saying

```
h(i)=1 => v(i)=0
```

This implication is easily implemented as an inequality:

```
v(i) <= (1-h(i))*D(i)
```

The complete model can look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ErwinKalvelagen.  I am new to modeling. Would you mind telling me the intuition behind this. Also it would be great if you can recommend a good resource (book/course) for modeling LPs.

Comment: Just plug in `h(i)=0`: `v(i)` becomes unrestricted. Plugging in `h(i)=1` yields `v(i)=0`. A good book is [Williams](https://www.amazon.com/Model-Building-Mathematical-Programming-Williams/dp/1118443330),

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen. Makes sense. Thanks for the book referral as well.

Comment: Hi @ErwinKalvelagen, I made a mistake while asking the question. The calculation of C is wrong. I have made a correction to the question. Would you mind looking at it one more time. Thanks.